# Any max and argmax?

Tags: dart

I want to use max and argmax on collections. I saw an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1319&q=max&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) for max but not argmax and it looks different to what I had in mind. Everything here is also applicable to min and argmin. Example of code with equivalent behaviour (minus error handling):

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  final nums = [3, 1, 2];
  final animalNames = ['cat', 'turtle', 'sheep'];
  final highest = nums.reduce(nums[0], (stored, curr) => math.max(stored, curr));
  final longest = animalNames.reduce(animalNames[0], longerString); 
  print('highest: $highest');
  print('longest: $longest');
}

String longerString(final String first, final String second) {
  if (first.length < second.length) {
    return second;
  } else {
    return first;
  }
}
```

I've been searching the API but haven't find anything like:

```dart
final highest = nums.max;
final longest = animalNames.argmax((name) => name.length);
```

Similar to Ruby [max and max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max).

Questions:

1. Are there API calls like these already (under some name I haven't checked)?
2. Are there any plans to make them?
3. Should I raise an issue?

Comment: Please file a bug and post a link to it here :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is, but here's a pretty trivial implementation based on your example:

```
animalNames.reduce("", (prev, cur) => prev.length > cur.length ? prev : cur);
```

This is faster than sorting if you only want to look it up once, but this can get a little unwieldy if you have complex logic for your argmax.

In one of the Dartisans videos, one of the devs mentioned how they're trying to make a lot of the common patterns easy, so I think something like this would have a pretty good chance of making it into the standard library if you make a good enough case for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't know that the ternary operator was in Dart. I'll state the case as best I can.